# how to remove categories from left column in customer account page in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I don't want to show categories in left column in customer account page.I have tried but didnot find the solution to solve this problem.I want any condition to remove categories only from customer acoount page.
If anyone have any idea,please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by xml

create a `local.xml` under `app/design/frontend/youpackage/youtemplate/layout/`
if you left panel category alias name is "`alias_name_of_left`" then you can do this by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>

        <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>alias_name_of_left</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

More Details at `http://magentist.com/magento_help/remove-sidebar-blocks-with-layout-update-xml/`

Comment: sorry but it is not working.I have created one local.xml page in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/ ,then added the above code then also it is not working

Answer (score 1):

In you `local.xml` file of your theme add as follow,

**Path:** `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/local.xml`

`<customer_account` handle is used for only customer account pages

```
<layout>
    <customer_account translate="label">
            <reference name="left">
                <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
            </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Flush caches and check.

Comment: i have created one local.xml page in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/layout/ ,and added the above code then also it is not working

Comment: @Dushyanth is the path app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/layout/
or 
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/

Comment: You posted the same paths

Comment: Your answer should work, I think he created the local.xml in template/layout Please add the path in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can remove block form customer.xml also for that first off all copy xml into you current theme. I have define the path.

Path: app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/customer.xml

Under customer_account handle.

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```